# ¿Enviar un mensaje a Whatsapp desde una pagina web?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Estamos en medio de un desarrollo de un sitio web para una pastelería, y dentro de los requerimientos que nos entregaron los analistas, nos pide lo siguiente:
"Confirmar pedidos primeramente realizando el registro del cliente y enseguida enviando un correo electrónico o un mensaje por whatsApp al administrador de la página".
La parte en la que estamos un poco retrasados es en la de Whatsapp.
¿Es posible hacer eso desde una pagina web? Desde un contacto que no se tiene registrado.
Gracias

Comment: Podrias evaluar usa una libreria como ser [WhatsAPI-Documentation sending messages](https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/wiki/WhatsAPI-Documentation#sending-messages) como veras puedes hacerlo directo desde PHP usando la funcionalidad de la libreria

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hasta el momento?

Comment: lo que necesitas es un mepe, no le envias el mensaje al wthassap sino un mensaje de texto msm le comprar al operador celular un acceso mepe y ya esta.

Comment: y con imagen como seria el código

Comment: @LeandroTuttini si no estoy equivocado, Whatsapi y otras librerías similares dejaron de funcionar ya que Whatsap no proporciona una API publica y no quiere que exista ninguna. Asi que diría que hoy por hoy no hay una solución para este problema...

Answer (score 1):

Ahí va el código con estilos. Lo agregas donde quieras y funciona:

```
<a href="intent://send/+34xxxxxxxxx#Intent;scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end" style="font-size:20px;padding:5px 12px;border-radius:5px;background-color:#189D0E;color:white;text-shadow:none;"> ›› Mensaje de WhatsApp </a>
```

Answer (score -1):

## Puedes Intentar  de estas formas. (Solo mobiles con What's app)

```js
  document.querySelector('#send_message').addEventListener('click',function(){

    var message = document.querySelector('#mensaje').value;
    var number = document.querySelector('#number').value;
    
    var url = "whatsapp://send?text="+encodeURIComponent(message)+"&phone="+encodeURIComponent(number)

    window.open(url);
    
  });
```

```html
Opcion 1 <br><br>
Texto
<input type="text"  name="send"  value="Hola mundo" id="mensaje" /> <br>
Numero
<input type="text"  name="number"  placeholder="ingresa el numero" id="number" />
<br /><br>
<button  id="send_message">Enviar mensaje</button>

<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
Prueba Rapida
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=Hola Mundo&phone=+18298615386">Enviar mensaje</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sza5r1q0/4/

Comment: Creo que este ejemplo no funciona así tal como está, en que lugar estableces el numero al cual se le enviará el mensaje?

Comment: Quieres enviar un mensaje a alguien que posiblemente no tenga como contacto?